# Spring boot Kotlin Project unable to resolve WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: kotlin, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I have made a spring boot project using the following configurations:

[image]

The following is my Gradle file:

[image]

But I am unable to access `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to configure in-memory security.

[image]

Comment: The imports look correct. Try running it from the command line to establish whether it's only a problem in the IDE.

Comment: Why are all the dependencies underlined in red?  That usually means a problem.